# Dynamically create and use new variable/parameter names and values in R

Tags: r, marginal-effects

For the following functions, I would like to make the variables (names and values) provided to datagrid() and 'by' dynamic, pulling from a dataframe and updating with each iteration of a for loop. Any ideas for how to implement this would be much appreciated!

```
 marginaleffects::avg_predictions(mice::as.mira(fits),
                            newdata=datagrid(HOMEETA1_Infancy=c(-0.87125,0.48375),
                                             HOMEETA1_Toddlerhood=c(-0.403875,1.123375),
                                             HOMEETA1_Childhood=c(-0.02475,1.60475)),                                            
                            by=c("HOMEETA1_Infancy","HOMEETA1_Toddlerhood","HOMEETA1_Childhood"))
```

Datagrid requires 'named arguments' and I have not figured out how to make those dynamic (via a list, dataframe, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If we have a named list or a data.frame, we can use `datagrid` with do.call

```
do.call(datagrid, yourdf)
```

---

A reproducible example

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ wt + drat, data = mtcars)
> datagrid(model = mod, wt = 1:2, drat = 3:4)
       mpg wt drat
1 20.09062  1    3
2 20.09062  1    4
3 20.09062  2    3
4 20.09062  2    4

> lst1 <- list(wt = 1:2, drat = 3:4)
> do.call(datagrid, c(list(model = mod), lst1))
       mpg wt drat
1 20.09062  1    3
2 20.09062  1    4
3 20.09062  2    3
4 20.09062  2    4
```